# top CPU consumers using ps command

Tags: solaris, cpu-usage

What is the difference between two commands, pls help to explain it.

ps -ef|sort +6|tail
   oracle   55676   1   0   03:06:16   -   0:36   oracleprod (LOCAL=NO)
   oracle   24876   1   0   02:52:56   -   0:40   oracleprod (LOCAL=NO)
   oracle   41616   1   0   07:00:59   -   0:44   oracleprod (LOCAL=NO)
   oracle   43460   1   0   02:45:05   -   0:53   oracleprod (LOCAL=NO)
   oracle   25754   1   0   08:10:03   -   1:01   oracleprod (LOCAL=NO)

> ps -ef|sort +5|tail
>      root    5440   2094   0   Nov 21   -   0:47    /usr/sbin/syslogd
>      root    9244      1   0   Nov 21   -   3:26   ./pcimapsvr.ip -D0
>      root   10782      1   0   Nov 21   -   4:41   ./pciconsvr.ip -D0

Why do both commands show different processes ? And if I keep on changing the value of 'sort +3' or reduce, the processes keeps on changing. What exactly is command all about ? Please help to explain.

Answer (score 1):

You are sorting the wrong columns using both an obsolete syntax and a wrong method. No surprise random processes show up.

You'll get the top consumers that way:

```
ps -ef | sort -n -k8 | tail
```

- `-n`  means sort numerically
- `-k8` means sort the the eight column (cumulative execution time)